# Why do I have so many simulators and how do I restore the basic platforms?

Tags: xcode6

Environment: Xcode v6.4

I just noticed that I have too may simulators.

Why has this happened and how do I control it?

[image]

Comment: Xcode Preferences - Downloads - Components <-- What do you have there?

Comment: Also Check Windows - Devices

Comment: I have the standard iOS 8.3 .. 7.1 Simulator components listed.  I check Devices - reflects the plethora of serial-coded simulators that I don't need.  I remove the entire Xcode bundle & support files and re-installed Xcode.  I still have this long list.

Comment: did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: No.  I cleared everything out and re-installed the SDK.