# Remove Simultor from Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I just updates my xcode in to 6.4 from 6 and after update it will show me a number of simulators so please help me if any one knows how to remove this simulators from Xcode

[image: Here is my screen]

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31438883/why-do-i-have-so-many-simulators-and-how-do-i-restore-the-basic-platforms?noredirect=1#comment50849221_31438883

Answer (score 4):

in `Xcode` menu select: **Window** => **Devices**

then select the device that you want to remove and `right click` and `remove`
as shown in the image below

[image]

Comment: Hey Aladin tnx for you Suggestion but its not working still.